# changing mathup font

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I'm just a poor latex user who wants customized font style. Here is my basic setting.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath,amsbsy}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lf]{Baskervaldx} % lining figures
\usepackage[bigdelims]{newtxmath} % math italic letters from Nimbus Roman (vvarbb for mathbb font)
\usepackage[bb=px, cal=cm, scr=boondoxo]{mathalfa}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathup}{OT1}{\familydefault}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
$\mathup{Category}$ $\text{Category}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

My problem is when I use \mathup in my setting, it uses Computer Modern instead of the Baskervaldx that I'm using as the text font. (Obviously using \text is bad decision because it is not a math mode...) Is there a way to fix this? Is the unicode-math package work for this? (I tried but somehow my overleaf has some problem with loading this package. Maybe conflict with some other parts of my code.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your code is incomplete. Are missed `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. Thank you.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks I edited.

Comment: Baskervaldx is not available in the OT1 encoding and this will produce a wealth of problems, for instance with Greek uppercase letters in math. I'd suggest `baskervillef` instead; add also the `baskerville` option to `newtxmath`.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding code to pretty-print the LaTeX code, and to fix a slight textual inaccuracy. (You had written that with your setup, `\mathup` was producing sans-serif output; I think you meant to write that LaTeX was using Computer Modern.) Feel free to revert.

Comment: Thanks both for @egreg and Mico, I found this useful but it is not exactly what I wanted. I come up with an easy solution and posted it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I found an easy solution. Instead of \mathup or \mathrm, one can use \normalfont to use the text font and keep it upright in any environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath,amsbsy}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{baskervald}
\usepackage[bigdelims]{newtxmath} % math font
%\usepackage[bb=px,cal=cm,scr=boondoxo]{mathalfa} % optional
\newcommand{\textup}[1]{\normalfont{\text{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\obeylines
$\textup{Category}$ $\text{Category}$
\end{document}
```

This gives the same as \text with upright even in the theorem environment.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution which, essentially, consists of incorporating all of @egreg's suggestions.

Note that with all recommendations in place, `\mathup` is more or less the same as `\mathrm`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath,amsbsy}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{baskervillef} % text font (lining figures are the default)
\usepackage[bigdelims,baskerville]{newtxmath} % math font
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathup}{T1}{\familydefault}{m}{n}
%\usepackage[bb=px,cal=cm,scr=boondoxo]{mathalfa} % optional

\begin{document}
\obeylines
$\mathup{Category}$ $\text{Category}$
$\mathrm{abc ABC 0123568}$
$\mathup{abc ABC 0123568}$
$\text{abc ABC 0123568}$
abc ABC 0123568
\end{document}
```